# How would cooperative and foraging chain work?

Tags: evolution

Imagine a Long Neck + Foraging + Cooperative combo.
It gains 2 foods from the food bank and feed the species at its right.
If the species at the right has foraging + cooperative, how many does it gain?
And how many gains the third species?

It seems like the first would gain 2, the next 2 and the next 1, but I am not sure. Someone said the first should gain 2 and the next 4 and the third should have 2.

Comment: I've retagged this to the North Star Games version of the game, rather than "Evolution: the Origin of Species," based on the cards you are referencing in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As clarified in the Climate rules, and as the system does it in the digital version, the food distributed would be 2 - 2 - 1.
-Creature A gets one food from long neck, it gets an additional from foraging.  Because it ate, the species to the right gets one plant food.
-Creature B gets one food and then an additional food from foraging. Because it ate, the species to the right gets one plant food.
-Creature C gets one food.  If it also had foraging it would get an additional food.

The designer (Dominic Crapuchettes) also clarified it in this thread here:  https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1419292/foraging-cooperation-and-order-eating

They also plan to post an official FAQ after the digital version is released.

Answer (score -1):

**As long as no species would exceed its Population, the three species would get 2, 4, and 4 Plant Food.** However, if at any time a food could not be taken as a result of Population limits, the numbers would be lower.

To work this out, let's say you have species {A}, {B} and {C}.

- {A} has the traits Long Neck, Foraging, and Cooperative.
- {B} has Foraging and Cooperative.
- {C} has neither.

After each trait triggers, I'll note the amount of cumulative food like this: *({A}:0; {B}:0; {C}:0).*

When the Food Cards are revealed,

1. {A} is going to take 1 Plant Food from the Food Bank because of Long Neck *({A}:1; {B}:0; {C}:0).*
2. {B} takes 1 Plant Food from the Food Bank because of {A}'s Cooperation *({A}:1; {B}:1; {C}:0).*
3. {C} takes 1 Plant Food from the Food Bank because of {B}'s Cooperation *({A}:1; {B}:1; {C}:1).*
4. {B} takes another 1 Plant Food from the Food Bank because of its Foraging trait *({A}:1; {B}:2; {C}:1).*
5. {C} takes another 1 Plant Food from the Food Bank because of {B}'s Cooperation *({A}:1; {B}:2; {C}:2).*

So far, the only thing {A} has used is the Long Neck trait. Continuing on:

6. {A} takes an additional 1 Plant Food from the Food Bank because of Foraging, which is triggered from the Long Neck *({A}:2; {B}:2; {C}:2).*
7. {B} takes 1 Plant Food from the Food Bank because of {A}'s Cooperation *({A}:2; {B}:3; {C}:2).*
8. {C} takes 1 Plant Food from the Food Bank because of {B}'s Cooperation *({A}:2; {B}:3; {C}:3).*
9. {B} takes another 1 Plant Food from the Food Bank because of its Foraging trait *({A}:2; {B}:4; {C}:3).*
10. {C} takes another 1 Plant Food from the Food Bank because of {B}'s Cooperation *({A}:2; {B}:4; {C}:4).*

Final tally: **{A} gets 2 Plant Food, {B} gets 4 Plant Food, and {C} gets 4 Plant Food.**

This assumes that Population limits are not met. If, for example, {A} met it's limit after just the Long Neck trait, steps 6-10 would be skipped because {A} didn't take a second Plant Food from its Foraging trait.

---

Rules can be found [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/102163/evolution-rules).

Comment: This is wrong - this is clarified in the Climate printed rules, and by how it works in the digital version.

Comment: Added my own answer, with a link to the game designer's feedback.